# MSBuild - Automatic File Generation and Compilation (NSwag)

Tags: c#, msbuild

After combining several resources, I am successfully generating an api client proxy with NSwag.MSBuild, but it is more verbose, repetitive, and inconsistent than I'd like and I'm hoping to understand or maybe clean up some of those issues.

```
<Target Name="NSwagCodeGeneration" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="$(NSwagExe_Net70) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration) --verbose" Outputs="obj\ClientV2.g.cs" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="OutputOfExec"/>
        <Output ItemName="Generated" TaskParameter="Outputs" />
    </Exec>
    <ItemGroup>
      <!--This is supposed to allow 'clean' to work but it does not work-->
      <FileWrites Include="@(Generated)" />
      <!--This needs to be here or the project finishes compiling 
            without including the ClientV2.g.cs file in the compile-->
      <Compile Include="@(Generated)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Target>
<!--This is the only way I could get the file to be deleted on clean-->
<Target Name="forceReGenerationOnRebuild" AfterTargets="CoreClean">
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)\obj\ClientV2.g.cs"></Delete>
</Target>
<!--This is the only way I could get the file to show up as an in-project-file 
    (which is helpful for debugging/understanding what is going on)-->
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)*.g.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This code works but I have the following items I'd like to clean up:

- FileWrites is supposed to track which files need to be removed upon "clean", but it did not work and required the Delete on CoreClean
- In order to generate and compile in the same project, I needed the first `<Compile Include>` within the exec target.  Otherwise the g.cs file would only be compiled if it existed BEFORE the build started (ie cleaned builds did not work the first time).
- That said, I still needed the second `<Compile Include>` in order for the file to show up in the solution explorer (which I feel makes it more obvious to the next developer what is actually happening in this project)
- I'd like cleanup the inconsistency and repetitive reference to "g.cs" files.  @Generated worked for the ItemGroup inside of the exec target, but the `<delete files>` and second `<compile>` both needed a different format (Delete did not like a wildcard, compile was not ideal with a direct ref because it showed the file to be missing).

[image: How it looks in the solution when everything is working right]

[image: how it looks after clean]

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work predictably by making sure the compile/include target was called before CoreCompile but still a dependency on the generation target:

```
<Target Name="NSwagCodeGeneration" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="$(NSwagExe_Net70) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration) --verbose" Outputs="obj\ClientV2.g.cs" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="OutputOfExec" />
        <Output ItemName="Generated" TaskParameter="Outputs" />
    </Exec>
    <ItemGroup>
        <!--This is supposed to allow 'clean' to work but it does not work-->
        <FileWrites Include="@(Generated)" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Target>
<!--This is the only way I could get the file to be deleted on clean-->
<Target Name="forceReGenerationOnRebuild" AfterTargets="CoreClean">
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)\obj\ClientV2.g.cs"></Delete>
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)\obj\ErrorMessageV2.g.cs"></Delete>
</Target>

<Target Name="UpdateGeneratedFiles" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="NSwagCodeGeneration" >
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)*.g.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Still can't get the CoreClean event to work so Im still adding deletes to be ran on clean